# How to set default checkbox status with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am used to doing this in jQuery

```
$('#RememberMe').attr('checked', true);
```

but I can't remember how to do it in Javascript I thought that

```
document.getElementById("RememberMe").value = "True";
```

would work, but it doesn't, it changes the value but does not create the visual check on the html.

I am trying to set the checkbox to on by default. here is the html

```
<input id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="false" />
```

Comment: If it is default, setting it in HTML is more appropriate, `<input id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="false" checked="true" />`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To change checkbox **state** try this:

```
document.getElementById("RememberMe").checked = true;
```

If you need to change the **value** of checkbox as an `input` element use:

```
document.getElementById("RememberMe").value = "New Value";
```

However, you can set default value and state in HTML markup:

```
<input id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="The Value" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: damn I knew it was something simple. Netbeans autocomplete was not my friend this time, it did not provide me with a .checked. Is there a way to set both value and state? with just one call? Basically I want value to be true it is checked if value is false it is unchecked. I guess value does not imply checked. Thanks

Comment: Possibly because only several DOM elements have `checked` attribute, and NetBeans does not differentiate it. Anyway, good that it helped :) **UPD:** `checked` and `value` are different attributes, so in JS you can't set them both with one call. However, if checkbox is not checked the value will not be sent to the server, so don't worry about `value`, set it by default and control only the `checked` state.

Comment: Hum... now that I tested it it still does not seem to work... hum

Comment: It should. Don't forget about `window.onload` or `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Yep i didn't it does change the value on the dom but it does not change the visuals on the page

Comment: To change the visual state of checkbox you anyway should use `element.checked = true`.

Comment: Hi, it turns out that jquery mobile changes states using css, so that was why i was not having any effect. So for jQM you need to change the class attribute.